# Install all dependencies of a package with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I want to install `pandoc` package using `pacman`:

```
$ sudo pacman -Sy pandoc
```

but it installs only `pandoc` without any dependency, so I got many times an error like this:

```
pandoc: error while loading shared libraries: libHSx509-system-1.6.7-
HvqJCDpdRB8Fi0TjXvBw2D-ghc9.0.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
directory
```

I tried this command to install dependencies, but not sure it should work:

```
# pacman -Si pandoc
```

The way I see is parsing the result from

```
# pacman -Qi pandoc
```

and install all deps, but I think there's a better way. Can anybody help?

Comment: What was the exact command you used to install pandoc? I just ran `sudo pacman -S pandoc` and was prompted to install a boatload of packages.

Comment: Yes, the command was `sudo pacman -S pandoc`. Moreover, I've already found a solution on [archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=281063), but after `sudo pacman -Syu` I did `sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring`, because the first command failed to import a key, how can I close the question?

Comment: Answer your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem:

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
```

It may fail with error like `Failed to Import PGP key` or something like that, to solve it I run:

```
$ sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring
```